# How to resolve the error occured while loading typo3 website url?

Tags: php, typo3

How to resolve the error associated with the website while loading which is giving message "oops, an error occured!"

Comment: please provide enough details regarding error and how it is coming.

Comment: actually that website was not developed by me, thats why I don't have much information about this technology so can I share my website url with you?

Comment: you need to check the error log and need to debug it yourself. nobody can help you out without access and coding part of the error.

Comment: Ok..I don't have much knowledge about typo3, still I will try my best! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should set the system context to "development". In the install tool you can find a configuration preset for it: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/6.2/In-depth/TheInstallTool/Index.html

Additionally you could set

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

within your TypoScript root template, which will give you more verbose exceptions in case the error was thrown while rendering a content element.

Comment: How to set this config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0 ??     because I don't have access of dashboard, having only folders named as file admin, typo3 conf, typo3 temp, uploads, t3liv so where I find this particular code?

Comment: you need a backend login as admin. then you could add that line to the main template **record**.

Comment: Ok..Thank You!!